# TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index on image filtering correlation operation

Tags: spyder

Hy..i  have a problem with this error on spyder when i try to code an image filtering in correlation operation.Did someone here can solve this,,,,i will show my syntax and the warning

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

def map_to_8bit(img_in):
    img_out = None
    img_out = ((img_in - img_in.min()) * 255/(img_in.max() - img_in.min())).astype(np.uint8)
    return img_out


def correlate(img_in, kernel):
    gray_img = cv.cvtColor(img_in, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_out = None
    
    stride = 1
    pad = 2
    w_in = gray_img.shape[1]
    h_in = gray_img.shape[0]
    filter_size = kernel
    k = filter_size // 2
    
    
    w_out = ((w_in+2*pad-filter_size)/stride)+1
    h_out = ((h_in+2*pad-filter_size)/stride)+1
 
    img_out = np.zeros(h_out, w_out)

    
    

    for i in range(0, img_out.shape[1]):
     for j in range(0, img_out.shape[0]):
        val = 0
        for u in range(-1*k, k+1):
            for v in range(-1*k, k+1):
                val += kernel[u+k, v+k] *img_in[i+u+k, j+v+k]
                img_out[i,j] = val
   

    return img_out

def main():
    bgr_image = cv.imread(r"./images/image.png")
    # program untuk menguji coba correlation filter
    kernel_1 = np.array([[1, 0, -1],
                         [2, 0, -2],
                         [1, 0, -1]])
    coorelation_output = correlate(bgr_image, kernel_1)
    cv.imshow("Correlation Output", map_to_8bit(coorelation_output))
    cv.waitKey(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

## **The warning problem that iam stuck on it**

Restarting kernel...

runfile('C:/Users/hp/exercise-3-alfirmansyah4212331013/exercise_3.py', wdir='C:/Users/hp/exercise-3-alfirmansyah4212331013')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)

File c:\users\hp\exercise-3-alfirmansyah4212331013\exercise_3.py:57
main()

File c:\users\hp\exercise-3-alfirmansyah4212331013\exercise_3.py:52 in main
coorelation_output = correlate(bgr_image, kernel_1)

File c:\users\hp\exercise-3-alfirmansyah4212331013\exercise_3.py:30 in correlate
img_out = np.zeros(h_out, w_out)

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

I am new on programming,So iam not really know what to do